# How to install openpyxl package in python using VS code on Mac

Tags: python

I have installed Python extention on VS code. The version that I use on VS code is 3.9. when I try to install openpyxl package on VS code console using code `pip install openpyxl` I get an error:

`bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip: No such file or directory`.

I have a pip.py file in the corresponding directory. What I am doing wrong?

Here is contents of my settings.json:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9"
```

}

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install openpyxl` to run pip module directly instead of through the bin wrapper. It might work for you. The error seems to be related to `pip` and not `openpyxl` specific. Try to install another package with `pip` you should get the same error :)

Comment: @Halfow Thank you, it worked! But now I've got another problem: when I try to run the code: import openpyxl, VS code gives an error: File "/Users/user/doc/HelloWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl: ImportError: No module named openpyxl. I don't know where I have to save my file, so that I could import the packages.

Comment: It seems to be a issue with your default python :) vscode uses.  You can test running the script form the command line with `python3 /Users/user/doc/HelloWorld.py`. As we installed `openpyxl` with python3 this should work. To set up vscode to use this python . Check your python3 location with `which python3` in your terminal you should get a path back. In VScode press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and fill the bar with `>Python: Select Interpreter`. Then select the python with the corresponding path or enter the full path we got from `which python3`

Comment: @Halfow So, you are right, when I run the file HelloWorld.py from console, it does import the packages. But I did now set the right interpreter, using the method you suggested, but still, the same error appears. But the python3 in the bin folder is not a folder, the files' format is alias, it's only 9 bytes large.

Comment: I suggest getting some more in-depth knowledge and reading a bit of the documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments . You probably want to configure `python.defaultInterpreterPath` in your settings.

Comment: @Halfow I edited my post and copied my settings.json file. It seems that the python.defaultInterpreterPath is configured. When I run the code `pip install sparse` on the console, when the directory is other that the directory where python 3.9 is located, I get an error:  No module pip.interval, pip is not a package. But when I change the directory to ..\bin (the same directory as indicated in settings.json file), and type `pip install sparse`, I get no response from the program.

Comment: Look at @Kovy Jacob s answer, if it works use the `/usr/local/bin/python3`  as python.defaultInterpreterPath . You will still need `python3 -m pip install` to install modules if you don´t set an alias for this. Ither do it as sugested by Jacob or  by `alias pip="python3 -m pip"`

Answer (score 0):

Try running this each time you open a terminal window:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Answer (score 0):

I opened the .zprofile file on my mac and added the line export PYTHONPATH="/Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/bin"

Save the file.

Close Terminal.app;

Start Terminal.app again, to read in the new settings, and type this:

echo $PYTHONPATH

It should show something like /Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/bin

https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html
~